# Can I use CFPropertyListWriteToStream with stderr?

Tags: c++, stream, core-foundation

I want to use `CFPropertyListWriteToStream` to write to `stderr`. If I put in `stderr` as an argument, I get the error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘FILE*’ to ‘__CFWriteStream*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘CFIndex CFPropertyListWriteToStream
```

How can I make a `CFWriteStream` object that writes to `stderr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the technique I found [here](http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/):

```
  CFWriteStreamRef stdoutStream = NULL;
  if (verbose) {
    CFURLRef devStdout =
      CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, CFSTR("/dev/stderr"),
                    kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
    stdoutStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFile(NULL, devStdout);
    if (stdoutStream == NULL)
      errexit("cannot create CFWriteStream for /dev/stderr");
    if (!CFWriteStreamOpen(stdoutStream))
      errexit("cannot open CFWriteStream for /dev/stderr");
  }
```